# No boot mode option in bios for Lenovo v470

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, uefi, mbr

My laptop (Lenovo v470) has a pre-installed Windows 7, but it doesn't start up and also startup repair doesn't work (missingosloader error). I want to re-install Windows 7 but all partitions are MBR and boot mode is UEFI and I get the error

```
Windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only installed on GPT disks."
```

I don't want to lose my data and I know there are approaches to change MBR to GPT without losing data but I don't want to take that risk. So I decided to change boot mode to Legacy. Unfortunately, in bios setup > boot menu, there is no boot mode option to change (not even disabled option). I can just change bootable media priority.

Is there any way to change boot mode through Ubuntu live or recovery command prompt?

*Edit*: Boot Menu that doesn't have boot mode.
[image: Boot Menu]

Configuration tab
[image: Configuration Menu]

Information tab
[image: BIOS information tab]

Security tab
[image: BIOS security tab]

Exit tab
[image: BIOS exit tab]

Comment: Since you're considering the use of a live session then do your backup bfrom it and then use Gparted to create a new - GPT - partition table (all partitions will be deleted). Now you can install in the preferred UEFI mode.

Comment: "all partitions are MBR and boot mode is UEFI and get the error" Then how was W7 installed in the first place? This makes no sense.

Comment: @moab This is pre-installed windows 7 by manufacturer. I don't know how.

Comment: Do you have Lenovo recovery media for the laptop? Or is there a Lenovo recovery partition?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It is the last solution I want to do. I want to know why I can't choose boot mode? Since it is installed before by manufacturer. Also it is possible that my product key (OEM key) will be invalid by formatting the disk. Is it normal that I can't choose boot mode?

Comment: @Moab yes there is a lenovo recovery partition.

Comment: The error is indicating you have enabled UEFI mode, and the boot environment has detected this fact, which means you can only install Windows on a GPT parttiion.  Since your HDD contains MBR partition, which means Legacy mode was enabled when Windows was installed, you should enable Legacy mode in order to boot into Windows.  The reason you are unable to boot into Windows is due to the fact, Legacy mode has been disabled, which likely is the entire reason you want to reinstall it? **At this point I would transfer your data off the HDD and reformat the HDD so you have a GPT partition.**

Comment: It is not possible to install Windows, while in UEFI mode, on a MBR partition.  So you can either, convert the disk to GPT, or enable Legacy mode and install Windows.  "is possible that my product key (OEM key) will be invalid by formatting the disk. Is it normal that I can't choose boot mode?" - **Windows 7 are never made invalid.**  There is always a solution that can be performed to activate Windows 7 with a legitmant license key.  All OEM license keys purchased from a legitmant retailer are legitmant.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to re-install because of startup problem that cannot be fixed by startup repair or other solutions. Also, as I said I don't see any option that I can enable Legacy mode in boot menu of BIOS. That's the problem.

Comment: Your start-up problem is due to the fact you have disabled Legacy Mode.  You need to enable it, and try booting into your existing installation, either way in order to avoid converting your disk to GPT you must enable Legacy Mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table"](https://superuser.com/questions/400449/troubleshooting-windows-cannot-be-installed-to-this-disk-the-selected-disk-has)

Comment: @Ramhound I added a picture of my boot menu to the question. How to enable Legacy Mode?

Comment: The option to enable Legacy Mode/Compatability Mode has to be there because it was disabled, and your current HDD is MBR, which means Windows did boot at one point..  Try the configuration tab.

Comment: @Ramhound added a picture of the configuration tab. There is nothing there, also there is nothing in the security tab too

Comment: @Vahid -  All I know the option to enable/disable UEFI mode has to be there, because it's currently enabled, yet you have a disk which had I presume a working Windows 7 installation on a MBR partition.  However, I don't know that for certain, since you have only indicated it currently does not work (which would make sense if Legacy mode was disabled).

Comment: @Vahid add images of every tab and we can guide you, its is there 100%

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers added other tabs. I think it is broken, may firmware update or F9 (Setup Defaults) help?

Comment: I don't see it lol, backup ur data via Linux USB reformat and install fresh windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the discussions in the comments, I should use Linux Live USB/CD to backup my files and then convert MBR disk to GPT (there are lots of tutorials for that with and without losing data).
For others that have the same issue, I suggest to consider F9 (Setup Defaults in the BIOS) and updating firmware as potential solutions (need to be investigated well). At the moment, I want to do backup and then MBT to GPT conversion.

Comment: I would never want to do some weird attempt to save my data during reformat. Use "GParted" from a Linux USB and reformat to GPT which would cause a full data wipe, then restore, but I'm OCD. From what I read you are correct, it is possible to convert without data loss! (Learn something on this site every day)